# User with 1 rep can post comments on own question/answer, bug or rule has been changed?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, reputation, comments

I just saw a comment from a user with rep of 1:

[image: screenshot of the "problem"]

I thought you need to have at least 50 to post a comment (if it's not your own question) in someone else answer. Is it a bug or something changed?

Comment: Was it on their own question/answer?

Comment: @Oded appears to be so -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770184/fixed-string-regular-expression-c-sharp/25770251#comment40300559_25770251

Comment: An answer written by someone else (but to his question).

Comment: This is by design. If the OP needs to clarify an answer to their question, they can comment on it, regardless of reputation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The comment poster was commenting on an answer to their own question.

These are always allowed (that is a question poster can *always* comment on their question and on the answers to their question).

Comment: You're right, time to turn off computer and breath fresh air...

Comment: I should also mention that another reason why you sometimes see comments from users with <50 rep is that they initially posted it as an answer, but then a moderator converted it into a comment (they can do that even if the poster doesn't have enough rep to comment).